# Cause error in Sqlite in android in where condition

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to read category id from men's wear from table category so i write query like this.

```
String q = "SELECT " + MENU_CAT_ID + " FROM " + CATEGORY_TABLE + " WHERE " + MENU_NAME + " = '" + name + "'";
```

but i got an error

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "s": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT menu_cat_id FROM category_table WHERE menu_name = 'Men's  Wear'
```

what can i do this case?

Comment: You need to escape "Men's Wear".

Comment: i think better way to user `database.query()` method and pass parameters as argument.. it'll help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the single quote in `Men's Wear` by doubling the single quote like this `Men''s Wear`.

When you are building your sql String you can use `DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(...)` to escape it for you like below:

```
String q = "SELECT " + MENU_CAT_ID + " FROM " + CATEGORY_TABLE 
         + " WHERE " + MENU_NAME + " = " + DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(name);
```